# HDMI 1080p Quality Issues

Tags: hdmi, nvidia-graphics-card, sony-vaio, 1080p

I'm having issues with a new 1080p monitor I purchased. The issue seems to occur when text is close together... the small space between the letters is a white colour when it should be something different. See the photo below for a visual.

It's not localized to a particular part of the monitor, it happens no matter where the offending text is.

I usually have the monitor setup as an extension but it also happens if it's a duplication AND doesn't show on the laptop monitor (which is also 1080p).

Details:
Monitor is a Samsung SyncMaster B2430 at 1080p using a HDMI cable
Graphics chip is a NVidia 330M (running on a Sony Viao laptop)

I have a feeling that it could be the cable... because I got the cheapest one in the shop (still $30 CAD). The monitor was around $300 CAD (inc tax) so it's not like a went cheap there...

Could the problem be the cable? The monitor? The graphics chip?

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem but managed to fix it.

The setting is on the Monitor Menu...

Menu > Setup & Reset > PC/AV Mode - set to 'PC'

That should do it!

Comment: Interesting... I'll give it a try when I get home. Thanks.

Comment: Brilliant! It worked - thanks for posting the answer after so much time.

Answer (score 2):

Ya, looks like it's a misconfigured ClearType. Go under Control Panel, Adjust ClearType.

Comment: I couldn't find a combination that fixed it... It's hard to do because the text they show is on a white background - so I can't see the issue resurfacing. Looks fine on the laptop monitor...

Answer (score 0):

It could be Microsoft's "ClearText" feature -- try turning that off to see if makes your text clearer (for some people it actually does).

Also make sure your video drivers are up-to-date (this is very unlikely to be the cause though).

What is your resolution set to?  Is it the optimal size for the monitor?  If not, then that could be part of the problem too.

Additionally, if this problem doesn't occur at first, but appears gradually over a short period of time, then it could be an overheating problem with your monitor (unlikely) or your video card (very likely).

Comment: I mucked around with ClearText but couldn't get a setting combination that fixed it (tried turning it off too). Resolution is set to 1080p (which is the native resolution. Problem appears straight off the bat from a cold boot. I just don't understand why it would be fine on the laptop monitor (@1080p too) but not on the external monitor...